# conectar php con mysql

Tags: php, base-de-datos, undefined

estoy intentando concetar mi base de datos con mi archivo php y me salta este error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in C:

como ED estoy usando visal estudio y laragon

he visto muchas formas para solucionarlo,modificar el archivo ini.php o agregar las variables de entorno, y nada

me he quedado en blanco, hay alguna otra forma de solucionarlo

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Si tienes PHP 7 o superior debes usar mysqli, todas las funciones mysql_ fueron sacadas del núcleo en todas las versiones posteriores a  PHP 7, dando en consecuencia un error de *`Undefined function`*

Comment: si uso la ultima version de php,